# AJAX support in smart phones in 2009

Tags: ajax, mobile, frameworks

How mature is AJAX support for mobile phones?
Are there mobile versions of some famous AJAX frameworks?
I would live even with a limited support for some ajax lib.

Answer (score 2):

iPhones won't cache anything larger than 25 KB uncompressed, which means libraries like jQuery and Prototype won't be cached like they would be on a normal computer. I suspect this sort of thing is the case with lots of other mobile browsers, too.

[XUI](http://xuijs.com/) is a slimmed down jQuery-like library that's fairly popular.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile phone market is very fragmented and you need to restrict yourself to a specific technology to get a useful answer. As far as I know there is no cross platform mobile framework available. However some mobile browsers are quite advanced and they will be able to handle jQuery or other libraries. I have seen jQuery run on S60 built in browser as well as Opera (not mini) at the same platform. I have also successfully run jQuery in mobile IE (Windows Mobile Professional Edition). However I wouldn't say it is safe to use jQuery on these platforms. You also want to ask the question regarding the size of the downloaded library as well as the execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

I think mobile ajax is not mature yet, but you should read this [wmlprogramming thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/wmlprogramming/message/29463), and check this preliminar version of [dojo mobile](http://alex.dojotoolkit.org/2009/01/webkit-mobile/) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [iWebkit](http://www.iwebkit.net) or [iUI](http://code.google.com/p/iui/) to build iPhone friendly web apps

Answer (score 0):

Peter-Paul Koch (ppk) started working on mobile device compatibility tests and has made [compatibility charts](http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html) for mobile devices.

Once these are documented, libraries authors can begin to abstract the differences. I don't know of many libraries that are cross-platform yet, but Peter's work should speed development.